# How can I fire a bullet from an actor's position?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I want to shoot a bullet from an actor.

I know I need a location in space to fire a bullet from, which I've got in the form of a model set as an actor. Now I need to create a new object (in this case, a bullet) with the same starting coordinates as that actor and set its movement direction to be the direction the actor is facing.

(Imagine a gun, a bullet is to be created at the coordinates of the tip of the barrel and the bullet will move forward in the direction that the gun was facing).

I can't figure out how to get the gun to generate the bullet or how to set the speed of the bullet. How can I do that in Unreal?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated First Person Shooter template? It contains everything you'd need to answer this question.

Comment: you mean in the New Project window? Im in Third person and am trying to not use Blueprints.

Comment: Yes, in the New Project window. You can generate it as C++, no Blueprints necessary. Just generate it and see how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new actor, you can use `SpawnActor`. [It's a member of `UWorld`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UWorld/SpawnActor/4/index.html), so you'll need one of those. `SpawnActor` takes a position and rotation.

Given your character actor instance called `Character` (the one firing the gun), and your custom bullet actor `ABullet`, you could do:

```
UWorld* World = characterActor->GetWorld();
ABullet* Bullet = World->SpawnActor<ABullet>(
  Character->GetActorLocation(),
  Character->GetActorRotation()
);
```

Now you have a `Bullet` you can work with. Actors in Unreal don't implicitly have a velocity property (they derive one from their movement component, if any). To handle velocity for your bullet, either give `ABullet` a velocity property and set it after you spawn (`Bullet->Velocity = FVector(...)`) and then update the actor's position in `ABullet`'s tick function, or attach a movement component, such as [`UProjectileMovementComponent`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/UProjectileMovementComponent/index.html) to the bullet actor. The latter is probably the better option.

Note that the above code for spawning the bullet spawns it at the world location of the character actor, which probably isn't ideal. Chances are you really want to spawn the bullet at the end of the character's gun barrel. A simple way to do this is to put a named socket on the character's mesh at the point you want the bullet to spawn, get the actor's static mesh component, and from there get the relative position of the named socket on the `UStaticMesh` object for the character. Add that relative location to the initial position given to the bullet to spawn it at the location of that socket.

---